# Remove HTML before insertBefore jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a field that inserts HTML when a user submits my form. If there is an error it inserts the error message before the form field. However, if the user submits multiple times it inserts multiple error messages, I would like to simply replace the error message so that it only appears once. I've tried to use replace but I couldn't get this way to work.

The form works via ajax so we don't reload the page to remove the errors, I need a way of replacing / removing them using jQuery.

Here is my jQuery code.

```
    $('<p class="form-error" id="' + errorKey + 'ErrorMessage">' + json.errors[errorKey] + '</p>')
.insertBefore(('[name="' + errorKey + '"]'))
```

Comment: Have you tried to disable submit button during sending data from the form?

Comment: The user can submit again if there are errors

Comment: The form works via ajax, so the page won't reload and remove the errors

Comment: Instead of inserting the error, could you not simply have an element whos visibility is toggled on/off on fail/success and populated with the error text?

Comment: Simple solution: Add an empty `div` with a unique id and add your created error message with [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select by `id` and remove:

```
$('#' + errorKey + 'ErrorMessage').remove();
```